# Элемент не исчезает полностью при hover transition

Tags: css, html5, hover, transition

Создал меню-навигацию:

```
.nav-item::before,
.nav-item::after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #ff0036;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
.nav-item::after {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.nav-item:hover::before,
.nav-item:hover::after {
    width: 65%;
}
```

[Ссылка на СodePen](https://codepen.io/darknessinme/pen/vYGOoey?editors=1100)

Моя задача добавить `hover` эффект при котором будет плавно появляться верхняя и нижняя граница элемента меню. Это я реализовал через псевдо-элементы `before` и `after`.

И вроде бы всё работает, но есть одно НО:

[image: активный hover]

Вот так выглядит активный `:hover`. А вот если водить мышкой туда-сюда, то с разной вероятностью может появиться вот это на месте предыдущего активного элемента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Маленький пиксель от `before` и `after` так и не сжался до `width: 0`. Почему так и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно переписать [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transition) на [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) что бы можно было добавить затемнение в конце:

```
.nav-items .nav-item:hover::before,
.nav-items .nav-item:hover::after {
    animation: forw 0.5s ease-out both;
}

.nav-items .nav-item::before,
.nav-items .nav-item::after {
    animation: rev 0.5s ease-out both;
}

@keyframes forw {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 65%
  }
}

@keyframes rev {
  0% {
    width: 65%;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Увы, не помогло. У меня на Хроме этот пиксель, если и появляется, то исчезает только если проскроллить вниз или навести курсор на "залагавший" элемент

Comment: @DarknessInme обновил ответ, теперь в Chrome все работает нормально

Answer (score 1):

Не анимируйте свойство width, анимируйте transform.
Когда вы анимируете такие свойства, как, типа: width, height, padding, margin браузер перерисовывают страницу браузера, что весьма затратно

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 26px;
}

a::before, a::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

a::after {
  transform-origin: right;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

a:hover::before, a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
</nav>
```

Пример с вашей реализацией анимации из центра:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 26px;
}

a::before, a::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

a::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

a:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(0.6);
}

a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(0.8);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
</nav>
```